# AJAX not working with certain localhost url's but is with others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#createTeamButton").on( "click", function() 
   {
    createTeamPage();
   });
});

function createTeamPage()
{   
  var createTeamSport = $("#newTeamClubDropdown").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "createTeam.php",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {createTeamSport: createTeamSport},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
    window.location.href = "createTeam.php";
  },
    error: function(result) 
    {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
}
```

when I click on `createTeamButton` i receive an error alert to say my AJAX has not worked. After a while of debugging I figured this was down to the URL I was using.

Within other files, i have an extremely similar jquery file but this one sends data to a PHP file named `editEvents.php`. So for testing purposes, i thought if I change the URL line of code to:

```
URL: "editEvents.php",
```

Ajax is successful and createTeam.php is shown due to the success handler. What I don't understand is why is createTeam.php not an acceptable file to send data to. both createTeam.php and editEvents.php are in the same folder and I know it's there as when testing sending the data to editEvents.php, createTeam.php was brought up successfully.

So why can I send the data to one PHP file and not another?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You're using a relative path, include an absolute path instead. _Should_ work (The url is relative to the **current page**, NOT to the .js file)

Comment: Give it full path with server name/address

Comment: @AlonEitan i gave this a go but still the same. All the files are in the same folder at the minute so if I'm correct in thinking this shouldn't matter? Also other files work without the absolute path name

Comment: @Josh Perhaps you don't have an element with `id=newTeamClubDropdown` on the other pages? I see you pass it the the script

Comment: @AlonEitan thats a good point, however whilst debugging i also removed the ajax call from the js file and setup a textbox that entered the value of that dropdown on click to test it. That worked successfully too

Comment: @Josh In that case you should open the developer tools, and in the **network tab** you should see what is being sent to the server and the response. I'm only guessing here because I can't see the whole code. So try my suggestion - Click on the button and you should be able to track the ajax request from the browser

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me your PHP code?? May be your PHP code is buggy. Here your ajax call is perfect. Some point I am mentioning below -
 1. Check your ajax URL is same as file location (Check browser url bar)
 2. Check PHP code 
 3. Debug your error function for better understand:

```
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
```

Comment: I placed this code into the js file and the alert message that came up showed nothing at all. I'll have a look at my receiving PHP file

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can not get your custom error parameter. Follow the following details and go to the given link to a better understanding of your function.

A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

Check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/